# How can I return only the fields I need after creating the user in sequelize?

Tags: database, orm, sequelize.js, backend, sequelize-typescript

So im using sequelize create function to store a user in postgres, using the try/catch block, like this:

```
try {
        const user = await User.create({
            name : name,
            email : email,
            hash : passHashed
        }, {
            returning: ["id", "name"]
        })
        console.log(user)
        res.json(user)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("error here", error)
        res.status(409).json(error)
}
```

however, even having specified the fields I want in the second parameter of the create method, everything is being returned

I already tried to return only the name, because it seems that the id will always be returned because it is the primary key.

sequelize always logs when an operation is done, and here it says it's returning what I need:

`[1] Executing (default): INSERT INTO "Users" ("id","name","email","hash","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4,$5) RETURNING "id","name";`

the user is always created correctly but

the returned user (console.log) and the response to frontend (res.json) is always returning everything.

how can i return as response only the fields i need, in this case id and name, and not all other fields like password, createdAt, email etc

Answer (score 0):

You should using `class-transformer` in **DTO** to transform your response data.
Using `@Exclude` with `@Expose` to be sure the attributes you want to expose. Docs [here](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer#skipping-all-properties-of-the-class)

*user.dto.ts*

```
import { Exclude, Expose } from 'class-transformer';

@Exclude()
export class UserDto {
   @Expose()
   id: number;

   @Expose()
   name: string;
}
```

In your function: *user.service.ts*, transforms the *userModel* to *userDto*

```
import { plainToInstance } from 'class-transformer';

try {
    const user = await User.create({
        name : name,
        email : email,
        hash : passHashed
    }, {
        returning: ["id", "name"]
    })
    return plainToInstance(UserDto, user);  // transform here
} catch (error) {
    console.log("error here", error)
    res.status(409).json(error)
}
```